# Does GeoJSON not support different projections?

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson

I have noticed that saving a GeoDataFrame with CRS as GeoJSON do not assign CRS to the file. While saving the same GDF as GeoPackage does.

Same happens in QGIS. Export to GeoJSON and there will be no CRS in the GeoJSON.

Does GeoJSON not support storing CRS information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The obsolete [GeoJSON 2008](https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) specification has a ["crs" member](https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#coordinate-reference-system-objects) to define a coordinate reference system (including projected).

GDAL/OGR has a [`RFC7946`](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#layer-creation-options) layer creation option, with default NO (thus GeoJSON 2008) to save CRS info. Setting `RFC7946=YES` changes [several aspects](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#rfc-7946-write-support) of the output file, including on-the-fly reprojection to EPSG:4326.

The current GeoJSON specification [RFC 7946](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946) does not normally allow a CRS specification, as the 2D coordinates are assumed to be in degrees of longitude and latitude. Exceptions are permitted for alternative coordinate reference systems if "all involved parties have a prior arrangement".

Comment: The current specification allows different crs but it does not define how to do it:  "However, where all involved parties have a prior arrangement, alternative coordinate  reference systems can be used without risk of data being  misinterpreted." See also https://www.ogc.org/projects/groups/featgeojsonswg.

Comment: I think all involved parties would be better arranging to use a data format suitable to modern GIS needs.